# samba shared folder on ubuntu 20.04 permission denied when writing from windows 8 machine

Tags: ubuntu, samba

I setup a shared samba folder on ubuntu 20.04 It appears on the Windows 8.1 machine on the same subnet but if I try to write to the folder I get a permission denied error

Answer (score 0):

You should check your `/etc/smb.conf` and see if your share is read-only or writable:

```
[your_share]
read only = no
```

You could also check if your user has the right to write to those files locally.